# How to make a random string array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, random

I'm not sure if my title is exactly what I need so let me explain.

What I'm doing is making a "simple" game that list a US State (at random into a label) and then below the label is 5 Buttons of which I am trying to change the text to the buttons to random State Capital (all of the Capitals need to be random except for the correct one) After hours of researching with no luck it seems that I am not the only one trying get help with this. If you can help it would be great!

```
Private Class Players
    Public Team As String
    Public Name As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal Team As String, ByVal Name As String)
        Me.Team = Team
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub
End Class

' Arraylist
Dim lstCapitals As New ArrayList

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim list As New List(Of Players)

    ' Capital Names
    lstCapitals.Add("Montgomery")
    lstCapitals.Add("Juneau")
    lstCapitals.Add("Phoenix")
    lstCapitals.Add("Little Rock")
    lstCapitals.Add("Sacramento")
    lstCapitals.Add("Denver")
    lstCapitals.Add("Hartford")

    ' Random number generator
    Dim randomInt As New Random

    ' Pulls a name randomly from the list
    Dim stringname As String = lstCapitals.Item(randomInt.Next(0, 6))
    '6 = lstCapitals.Count / one line up

    ' Show the name
    'stateNamelbl.Show()
     'NOT SURE IF I NEEDED THIS OR NOT THATS WHY ITS COMMENTED OUT
    'Dim RandomList = From RndList In (From xitem In list Select xitem Group By xitem.Team Into First()) _
    '      Select RndList _
    '      Order By Rnd()

    For Each item In lstCapitals
        Randomize()
        MsgBox(item.Team)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry my code doesn't make much since. I've only been working with vb for a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code doesn't explain how you choose the US State so I assume that you will have the value in a string somewhere. Here is a simple method you could use to generate a random string array to hold the values of the state capitals:

```
Dim sCorrectStateCapital As String = "Denver"   ' This is hardcoded to "Denver" assuming that "Colorado" was the current US State you are playing the game for - you need to come up with your own logic to figure out how this works as I have no idea how you are choosing the State
Dim nButtonCount As Integer = 5 ' This is hardcoded to five since you have five buttons
Dim sCapitalsArray(nButtonCount - 1) As String  ' Create the string array to hold the chosen capitals

' Loop five times and choose a different state capital each time

For i As Int32 = 0 To sCapitalsArray.Length - 1
    Dim nTempIndex As Int32 = randomInt.Next(0, lstCapitals.Count - 1)  ' Save the index value of the arraylist that we are choosing
    sCapitalsArray(i) = lstCapitals.Item(nTempIndex)    ' Populate the captials array
    lstCapitals.RemoveAt(nTempIndex)    ' Remove the selected capital from the list of possible choices since we do not want to choose it again
Next

' Test to see if the capitals array already contains the "correct" value

If Not sCapitalsArray.Contains(sCorrectStateCapital) Then
    ' The correct value is not already in the list so we overwrite one of the values in the array at a random index
    sCapitalsArray(randomInt.Next(0, sCapitalsArray.Count - 1)) = sCorrectStateCapital
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The Form below has...

3 Labels: lblState, lblScore, lblAnswer

5 Buttons: btnCapital1, btnCapital2, btnCapital3, btnCapital4, btnCapital5

[image: State Capitals Quizzer]

```
Public Class frmStateCapitalsQuiz

    Public Class State

        Public Name As String
        Public Capital As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal data As String)
            Dim values() As String = data.Split(",")
            Me.Name = values(0)
            Me.Capital = values(1)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Me.Capital & ", " & Me.Name
        End Function

    End Class

    Private R As New Random
    Private Count As Integer
    Private Correct As Integer
    Private States As List(Of State)
    Private CurrentState As State = Nothing
    Private CurrentStateSet As List(Of State)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadStateData()
        GenerateQuestion()
        lblScore.Text = "Score: "
        lblAnswer.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadStateData()
        States = New List(Of State)
        Dim StateData As String = "Alabama,Montgomery;Alaska,Juneau;Arizona,Phoenix;Arkansas,Little Rock;California,Sacramento;Colorado,Denver;Connecticut,Hartford;Delaware,Dover;Florida,Tallahassee;Georgia,Atlanta;Hawaii,Honolulu;Idaho,Boise;Illinois,Springfield;Indiana,Indianapolis;Iowa,Des Moines;Kansas,Topeka;Kentucky,Frankfort;Louisiana,Baton Rouge;Maine,Augusta;Maryland,Annapolis;Massachusetts,Boston;Michigan,Lansing;Minnesota,St. Paul;Mississippi,Jackson;Missouri,Jefferson City;Montana,Helena;Nebraska,Lincoln;Nevada,Carson City;New Hampshire,Concord;New Jersey,Trenton;New Mexico,Santa Fe;New York,Albany;North Carolina,Raleigh;North Dakota,Bismarck;Ohio,Columbus;Oklahoma,Oklahoma City;Oregon,Salem;Pennsylvania,Harrisburg;Rhode Island,Providence;South Carolina,Columbia;South Dakota,Pierre;Tennessee,Nashville;Texas,Austin;Utah,Salt Lake City;Vermont,Montpelier;Virginia,Richmond;Washington,Olympia;West Virginia,Charleston;Wisconsin,Madison;Wyoming,Cheyenne"
        For Each pair As String In StateData.Split(";")
            States.Add(New State(pair))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub GenerateQuestion()
        Dim shuffledStates = States.OrderBy(Function(x) R.NextDouble()).Take(5).ToList
        CurrentState = shuffledStates(R.Next(shuffledStates.Count))
        lblState.Text = CurrentState.Name
        btnCapital1.Text = shuffledStates(0).Capital
        btnCapital2.Text = shuffledStates(1).Capital
        btnCapital3.Text = shuffledStates(2).Capital
        btnCapital4.Text = shuffledStates(3).Capital
        btnCapital5.Text = shuffledStates(4).Capital
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCapitals_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCapital1.Click, btnCapital2.Click, btnCapital3.Click, btnCapital4.Click, btnCapital5.Click
        Dim SelectedCaptial As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

        lblAnswer.Text = CurrentState.ToString
        Count = Count + 1
        If SelectedCaptial.Text = CurrentState.Capital Then
            lblScore.BackColor = Color.Green
            Correct = Correct + 1
        Else
            lblScore.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        Dim percentCorrect = CInt(CDbl(Correct) / CDbl(Count) * 100)
        lblScore.Text = String.Format("Score: {0} / {1}, {2}% Correct", Correct, Count, percentCorrect)

        GenerateQuestion()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you both for the response!

Idle_Mind I tried to use your exact code in a new form to see how it worked but I get an error at line 56. It did nothing on form load but when I click a button it showed the error message.

lblAnswer.Text = CurrentState.ToString '<- the error points to CurrentState.ToString ERROR MSG(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
        Count = Count + 1
        If SelectedCaptial.Text = CurrentState.Capital Then
            lblScore.BackColor = Color.Green
            Correct = Correct + 1
        Else

Comment: I figured it out. I form load was not correct. Works great! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Once I get 15 rep I'll vote yours up! Would it be very easy to make it to where once it displays that state it doesn't show again unless the game is restarted?